# Which parts of a bike have reversed (left-handed) threads?

Tags: maintenance

Which parts of a bike have reversed (left-handed) threads?

There's 1) the non-drive-side left pedal-to-crank threading and 2) the drive-side right bottom bracket cup (apparently sometimes called the fixed cup).

Is there anything else?

Comment: What country is the bike from? French/Italians are contrary to the usual rules.

Comment: @Batman Mine was made in China for the American market but I'm also asking for general knowledge including how it's done in other places.

Comment: My point is that you have to be careful. There are bikes which use the exact opposite of the sane typical choices.

Comment: The left pedal, always! The BB depending on the standard.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed gear hubs have left-handed threaded lock rings, so that they can't be loosened when the cog that is on right handed thread is turned counterclockwise.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found that a freewheel internal thread is left-handed.  This is the access for the guts of the freewheel's insides, so pawls and little bearings inside, and generally not user serviceable.

Answer (score 2):

On some full suspension mountain bikes some of the pivot/linkage bolts can be reverse threaded.  Manufacturer dependant though.

Answer (score 1):

Bearings inside left pedals may be held in with LH threads.

Comment: That will depend on the particular kind of pedal. As far as I remember, the nut on the tip of the axle on CrankBrothers pedals is right handed in both pedals. The bearing itself is just pressed-in and held by a nut.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Yeah, all the CB pedals I've encountered have been RH threaded axles on both sides. However, Shimanos are different: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72067/which-shimano-pedals-have-reverse-threaded-bearing-adjustments

Answer (score 0):

Rock Shock air forks, at least the ones I saw, have reverse threads in lower stanchions. (bottom cap nuts)

Comment: Which fasteners are you referring to? If you’re talking about the bolts holding the lowers onto the air shafts, I’ve found those to be all normal threaded…

Comment: No. The ones securing the shafts. Not the bolts securing the stanchion to leg.